# Delphi TLabel with long text

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

In Delphi (10.3.2 in this case but also in earlier versions) I have a TLabel which has text too long to fit. Word wrap is unchecked for the TLabel.

On Windows, the text is truncated and an ellipsis is added at the end of the TLabel.

On MacOS, the text is word wrapped into two lines, both of which are unreadable because they are clipped at the top and at the bottom.

How do I get the TLabel to behave on MacOS as it does on Windows?

Comment: I suppose you are under an NDA since your are using Delphi 10.3.2. This is not the right place to write about bugs in an unreleased version. BTW, I do not have this problem in Delphi 10.3.1.

Comment: 10.3.2 is out. https://www.embarcadero.com/radoffer

Comment: You are right, it is out, then I can tell you that I have the same problem with 10.3.2 (beta version) and I believe I reported an issue about it - but since I am not at my work computer right now, I cannot find it. Anyway, I made a workaround to solve it: Trimming := TTextTrimming.Character